# Spring Security 5 rest client with OAuth2

Tags: spring, spring-security

I would like to implement a client which should simply send some rest calls with a OAuth2 token. Using spring-security-oauth it was pretty easy to use the OAuth2RestTemplate with a client-credentials flow. Today I saw most of those classes are deprecated in 2.4.0 and the recommendation is to use Spring Security 5. I've googled around and looked into the Migration Guide [1] but I've not understood what I've to do to perform some simple rest call which fetches a token with Spring Security 5. I think I'm even not sure what kind of libraries are needed. So what I'm basically is looking for is a way to provide a client-id, client-secret and a  tokenendpoint programatically (not via properties) to some kind of rest template and send a request to a specific url.

--edit--

I found a way of using the web client without using the properties but rather using the `ClientRegestration` object. I'm not sure if that is a recommended way:

```
 @Test
    public void test() {
        WebClient webClient = getWebClient();
        ResponseSpec retrieve = webClient.get().uri("https://somepath")
                .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId(REG_ID)).retrieve();
        Flux<String> result = retrieve.bodyToFlux(String.class); // flux makes no sense here, use Mono instead 
        Mono<List<String>> response = result.collectList();
        List<String> block = response.block();
        System.out.print(block);
        System.out.print("debug");
    }

    public WebClient getWebClient() {
        Builder clientRegestrationBuilder = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(REG_ID);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientId(CLIENT_ID);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.tokenUri(TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientRegestrationBuilder.build();

        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repo = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(repo,
                new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
```

Regards
monti

[1] https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/wiki/OAuth-2.0-Migration-Guide

Comment: If you are looking for an OAuth2 integration with the Spring `WebClient` and Spring Security, have a look at these examples: https://rieckpil.de/spring-webclient-oauth2-integration-using-github-as-an-example/ or https://rieckpil.de/spring-webclient-oauth2-integration-for-spring-web-servlet/ for servlet based applications

Comment: Thanks for providing the links. I'm still kind of confused but found a way to do what I've done with the rest template. Updated my post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code is a unit test which shows how a `ClientRegistration` can be done programatically. In "real" spring scenario I guess the `ClientRegistration` should be provided as bean and finally injected as a list to a `ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository`...

```
 public void test() {
        WebClient webClient = getWebClient();
        ResponseSpec retrieve = webClient.get().uri("https://somepath")
                .attributes(ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction.clientRegistrationId(REG_ID)).retrieve();
        Flux<String> result = retrieve.bodyToFlux(String.class); // flux makes no sense here, use Mono instead 
        Mono<List<String>> response = result.collectList();
        List<String> block = response.block();
        System.out.print(block);
        System.out.print("debug");
    }

    public WebClient getWebClient() {
        Builder clientRegestrationBuilder = ClientRegistration.withRegistrationId(REG_ID);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientId(CLIENT_ID);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.clientSecret(CLIENT_SECRET);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.tokenUri(TOKEN_ENDPOINT);
        clientRegestrationBuilder.authorizationGrantType(AuthorizationGrantType.CLIENT_CREDENTIALS);
        ClientRegistration clientRegistration = clientRegestrationBuilder.build();

        ReactiveClientRegistrationRepository repo = new InMemoryReactiveClientRegistrationRepository(clientRegistration);

        ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction oauth = new ServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientExchangeFilterFunction(repo,
                new UnAuthenticatedServerOAuth2AuthorizedClientRepository());
        return WebClient.builder().filter(oauth).build();
    }
```